# Can anybody explain me why this code is not working?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm learning C++. Now, I'm trying to make one sample related with overloading operators of an object. My object (called `Contador`) has different methods and variables which help user to count iterations.

Header file of the object:

```
class Contador
{
private:
    int* Valor;
    int* Salto;

public:
    Contador(int Valor_Inicio = 0, int Salto = 1);
    ~Contador();

inline int Get_Valor() const { return *Valor; }
inline int Get_Salto() const { return *Salto; }

inline void Incremento() { Set_Valor(Get_Valor() + Get_Salto()); }

inline void operator++ () { Set_Valor(Get_Valor() + Get_Salto()); }

void Set_Valor(int Valor);
void Set_Salto(int Salto);
```

};

Cpp file of the object:

```
// Librerias Propias
#include "Contador.h"

Contador::Contador(int Valor_Inicio, int Salto)
{
    Set_Valor(Valor_Inicio);
    Set_Salto(Salto);
}

Contador::~Contador()
{
    delete Contador::Valor;
    delete Contador::Salto;
}

void Contador::Set_Valor(int Valor)
{
    delete Contador::Valor;
    Contador::Valor = new int(Valor);
}

void Contador::Set_Salto(int Salto)
{
    delete Contador::Salto;
    Contador::Salto = new int(Salto);
}
```

The `main()` function of the sample has 2 different `for` loops. In the first one, I call `Incremento()` method and in the second one I call the overloaded operator.

Main function:

```
void main()
{
    // Genero el elemento de analisis.
    Contador* contador = new Contador();

    // Realizo el bucle con la función de incremento.
    std::cout << "Incremento()" << std::endl;
    for (contador->Set_Valor(0); contador->Get_Valor() < 3; contador->Incremento())
    {
        // Escribo algo.
        std::cout << "Iteracion actual: " << contador->Get_Valor() << std::endl;
    }

    // Realizo el bucle on el operador sobrecargado
    std::cout << "operador sobrecargado" << std::endl;
    for (contador->Set_Valor(0); contador->Get_Valor() < 3; contador++)
    {
        // Escribo algo.
        std::cout << "Iteracion actual: " << contador->Get_Valor() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The problem appears when main function passes the first iteration of the second loop. It throws one exception in `Get_Valor()` method.

[image: Exception image]

It seems to me that it change the memory addres of the pointer `Valor`in some place, but I can`t find where.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You can rewrite this code **without using any pointers at all**.

Comment: In the constructor, you delete an uninitialized pointer, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: There are two errors in this code, both related to pointers (see the other posts and comments). There is absolutely no need to use pointers in this class, you are just making things difficult for yourself. It seems you could benefit from reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ which will give you a more balanced introduction to C++.

Comment: @john I know I can rewrite this code without using pointer. However, I want to use pointers in order to use them correctly.

Comment: Not using pointers when they are not needed *is* using them correctly. As a reasonable approximation, `new` should not appear in code you write.

Comment: Another undefined behavior: if allocation fails, you delete a pointer that has not been allocated. Example: `{ Contador c; c.Set_Valor(1); /* what if new fails? */ }`. Maybe, you want to use `std::unique_ptr` instead if you insist on pointers.

Comment: @pH4ngH0st Well a third error concerning pointer use is that you are not following the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Pointers are difficult, and in modern C++ not particularly useful. There might be better areas for you to concentrate on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contador++` does not do what you think it does - `contador` is a pointer, not a `Contador`, so it will make `contador` point to something that does not exist.
You need to dereference the pointer.

However, `*contador++` also increments `contador` - it is `*(contador++)` - and `(*contador)++` does not compile because you have only overloaded the prefix operator (the postfix operator has the prototype `operator++(int)`.

So, `++*contador` will do what you want.

You can avoid many similar problems, and the clunky syntax, by not using pointers unnecessarily.

Comment: Excellent answer! You even answered the answers' problems, and the problems of the comments to the answer's answers!

Answer (score 2):

The expression `contador++` increments the address that `contador` (a pointer) points to! So, after the first iteration, the pointer will be completely invalid.

To call the increment operator, you need: `++(*contador)` which first dereferences the pointer to the object pointed to, then effects that object's increment operator.

Comment: Since he's new to c++ may be more clear to read `(*contador)++`

Answer (score 2):

3 coding issues:

- `main` shoudl return `int`.
- `Valor` and `Salto` are not initialized in constructor.
  `Contador::Set_Valor` and `Contador::Set_Salto` requires initialized pointers (as you delete them).

  Easy fix is:

  ```
  class Contador
  {
  private:
      int* Valor = nullptr;
      int* Salto = nullptr;
  //...
  };
  ```
- Last issue is in your last loop:

  ```
  for (contador->Set_Valor(0); contador->Get_Valor() < 3; contador++)
  ```

  As `condator` is a pointer (not pointing on an array), accessing `condator[1]` would be UB.
  You wanted `++(*condator)` (`operator++ ()` is pre-increment whereas `operator++ (int)` is post-increment).

Finally, avoiding usage of all those pointers would simplify code (and no bother with rule of 3 you break):

```
class Contador
{
private:
    int Valor;
    int Salto;

public:
    Contador(int Valor = 0, int Salto = 1) : Valor(Valor), Salto(Salto) {}
    ~Contador() = default;

    int Get_Valor() const { return Valor; }
    int Get_Salto() const { return Salto; }

    void Incremento() { Set_Valor(Get_Valor() + Get_Salto()); }
    void operator++ () { Set_Valor(Get_Valor() + Get_Salto()); }

    void Set_Valor(int Valor) { this->Valor = Valor;}
    void Set_Salto(int Salto) { this->Salto = Salto;}
};

int main()
{
    Contador contador;

    std::cout << "Incremento()" << std::endl;
    for (contador.Set_Valor(0); contador.Get_Valor() < 3; contador.Incremento())
    {
        std::cout << "Iteracion actual: " << contador.Get_Valor() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "operador sobrecargado" << std::endl;
    for (contador.Set_Valor(0); contador.Get_Valor() < 3; ++contador)
    {
        std::cout << "Iteracion actual: " << contador.Get_Valor() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another issue as well. If `new` fails in `Set_Valor` that has not been called from a constructor, then `delete` in the destructor (or, subsequent `Set_Valor`) will cause UB. Just to make your answer complete.

Comment: @DanielLangr: In OP's case, `contador`'s destructor isn't called as it leaks, so it is not an "issue" ;-) (good catch BTW).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers.
As I could see  `Contador* contador = new Contador();` code also contains UB (undefined behaviour)
This call is equal to constructor with parameters Contador(0, 1) 
which will do `Set_Valor` and `Set_Salto`  which call delete first but at this moment content of this variables is not guaranteed to be `nullptr` so you might corrupt data. Also compiler if it sees UB might optimize out all other code since it's already UB and it can change behaviour anyway it wants for example throw it away completely. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633